# sql : join table ,return record with count 1

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table `mt table`
It stores transactions.
Each transaction has a billing and its joined by external_id field

I want to return data from mt table where the billing table has only one joined record.

So in this case i would return (mttable, id:4 and 2. It's external_id 111 and 222 has only one record in billing table)

```
mt table
id        external_id
---       -----------
1          444
2          222
3          333
4          111

billing table

id      external_id
---     -----------
3        444
4        444
5        333
6        333
7        222
8        111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

```
select mt.*
from mt
where (select count(*)
       from billing b
       where mt.external_id = b.external_id
      ) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a basic `GROUP BY` query here:

```sql
SELECT mt.id, mt.external_id
FROM mt
INNER JOIN billing b ON b.external_id = mt.external_id
GROUP BY mt.id, mt.external_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mt WHERE external_id IN 
(SELECT external_id FROM billing GROUP BY external_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few other options also, Like `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
  from mt t join billing b on t.external_id = b.external_id 
 where not exists 
    (select 1 from billing bb
       where mt.external_id = b.external_id and b.id <> bb.id);
```

Or You can also use the analytical function `count` as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*, count(1) over (partition by b.external_id) as cnt
  from mt t join billing b on t.external_id = b.external_id)
where cnt = 1
```